# How to pass ternary value to variable in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

For below `nxsId` I need to pass null when `this.nxsId` is empty

```
public nxsId: any; // declared as any
nxsId: this.nxsId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"nxsId": this.nxsId !== '' ? this.nxsId : null
```

Above statement, if `this.nxsId` is empty then it will assign a `null` value else will assign a value of `this.nxsId`.

Comment: Hi Santosh , if nxsId is null im getting undefined value.

Comment: then change condition before the question mark if condition true will take value of this.nxsId or on false will take null value